# there is a error parsing the package (visual studio ionic app)

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

i have build ionic app with visual studio 2015 and i have also krecated a key using below cmd command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\raykamerm -alias erm -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

and this is my build.json file

```
{
 "android": {
     "release": {
         "keystore":"c:\\raykamerm",
         "storePassword":"123456",
         "alias":"erm",
         "password":"123456",
         "keystoreType":""
       }
   }
}
```

i get the output in bin\release and  android-release.apk as file name , but when i try to install it on device , i get the error

```
**
```

> `there is a problem parsing the package`

**

i have enbaled unknown sources in my android device , but still i get the error?

what is wrong ?
my cordova version is 6.2.0
[image]

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your keystore file path should be like this {C:/youkeystore.keystore} 
with filetype extension , Yours is c:\raykamerm .. I think that's causing problem